# Displaying uploading buttons depending on files uploaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a project model where i can create projects and to each project upload videos and photos. I'm using nested attributes. My form displays 5 photo upload buttons and 5 video upload buttons. I want to hide the buttons that are used. For example: If I've uploaded 1 photo and 2 videos I want my edit form to display 4 upload photo buttons and 3 for the videos.

Right now, if a photo is uploaded it hides 1 upload button from the photos and one from the videos. Does anyone know how to make this possible?

Here is my controller.

```
 def new
        @project = Project.new()
        (5 - @project.assets.length).times { @project.assets.build }


        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # new.html.erb
          format.xml  { render :xml => @project }
        end


      end

      # GET /projects/1/edit
      def edit
          @project = Project.find_by_permalink(params[:id])
          (5 - @project.assets.length).times { @project.assets.build }


      end
```

Gems:

```
gem "paperclip", "~> 3.5"

# handels video upload
gem "paperclip-ffmpeg", "~> 1.0.0"
```

Project Model:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_permalink :title
    default_scope :order => 'created_at desc'
    attr_accessible :title, :description, :assets_attributes, :dependent => :destroy
    validates_uniqueness_of :title
    validates_presence_of :title
    has_many :assets, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets, :allow_destroy => true

end
```

Asset Model:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
    require 'paperclip'
    require 'paperclip-ffmpeg'

    belongs_to :project, :foreign_key => "project_id"
    attr_accessible :project_id, :photo, :video
    has_attached_file :photo, :styles => {  :thumb => "130x130#", :medium => "300x300#", :small => "160x160#"}
    has_attached_file :video, :styles => {
    :mobile => {:geometry => "400x300", :format => 'flv', :streaming => true}
  }, :processors => [:ffmpeg, :qtfaststart]   


end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to differentiate the video-assets and image-assets. That will do. 
Also, if you can share with us what gems are being used, we could help better.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved it by making a "add" button, to add a file field on request.(Did one for the video upload and one for the photo upload.)**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="newPaperclipFiles col-md-4 col-md-offset-1" style="overflow: hidden;">
    <h3 style="color:rgb(31,154,207);">Upload a Photo</h3>
    <hr style="margin-left: -20%; width: 280px !important;"></hr>
    <%= f.fields_for :assets do |asset_photo| %>
      <% if asset_photo.object.new_record? %>
        <div class="btn custumbtn btn-xs" id="duplp" onlick="duplicatep()">Add</div>
        <div id="duplicaterp"> 
          <%= asset_photo.file_field :photo %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('duplp').onclick = duplicatep;

var i = 0;
var original = document.getElementById('duplicaterp');

function duplicatep() {
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
    clone.id = "duplicaterp" + ++i;
    original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
}
</script>
```